# Why does the integer representation of a floating point number offer a piecewise linear approximation to the logarithm?

Tags: math, floating-point, logarithm, approximation

If you were reading news about developments in graphics in the 1990s, you might have followed Jim Blinn's column in *IEEE Computer Graphics & Applications*, "Jim Blinn's corner." In the summer of 1997 you would have opened your issue to a column called "[Floating-Point Tricks](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/595279)". All of the tricks are based on the following chestnut of knowledge Blinn passes along from Steve Gabriel and Gideon Yuval, two old hands at microsoft:

"*If you only deal with positive numbers, the bit pattern of a floating point number, interpreted as an integer, gives a piecewise linear approximation to the logarithm function*"

My question is, what is it about floating point numbers which gives rise to this characteristic?

### Demonstration

```c
// These will result in undefined behavior
// and are not the 'right' way to do this
// but I am following Blinn 1997 here
int AsInteger(float f) {
    return * ( int * ) &f;
}

float AsFloat(int i) {
    return * ( float * ) &i;
}

// FISR demonstrating the logaritmic nature of the floating-point numbers
// The constant chosen is not "magic" but that which replaces the lost
// exponents from the shift of the number as an integer.
float BlinnISR(float x) {
    int i;
    float y;
    // 0x5F400000 = 1598029824
    // which is (AsInteger(1.0f) + (AsInteger(1.0f) >> 1))
    i = 0x5F400000 - ( AsInteger(x) >> 1);
    y = AsFloat(i);
    // Blinn uses 1.47 and 0.47 not 1.5 and 0.5 
    // which are what you would get from differentiating
    y = y * (1.47f - 0.47f * x * y * y);
    return y;
}
```

The above, a [recreation of Blinn's example code](https://github.com/hyland-uw/FISR-historical/blob/main/src/FISR-instrumentation.c), shows how it works practically for the inverse square root.

Remember that 1 / sqrt(x) is the same as x<sup>(-1/2)</sup>. So if we have access to a table of logarithms one way to find the square root is to take the natural log of x<sup>(-1/2)</sup> which gives you -1/2 * ln(x). If you exponentiate this you get 1 / sqrt(x) = e<sup>((-1/2) * ln(x))</sup>.

Right shifting the integer representation of the float bits gives us an approximation of a division by two of the *logarithm* of the input floating point number (this is our 1/2 * ln(x)). This is subtracted from the restoring constant, here just `0x5F400000`, not yet 'magic' so we have essentially -1/2 * ln(x). Returning that to a float serves as our exponentiation step. We then have a number which serves as a good first input into Newton's method.

### What it looks like

Visually, you can see the relationship here (Blinn 1997, p. 81):

[image: relationship of integer and floating point logarithm]

A similar, idealized graph appears in Mitchell 1961 (p. 513, linked below):

[image: logarithm and straight line approximation]

This same relationship is shown in Jean-Michel Muller, ”[Elementary Functions and Approximate Computing](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9106347),” in Proceedings of the IEEE, vol. 108, no. 12, p. 2137, Dec. 2020

[image: logarithm and straight line approximation from Muller]

### Where this applies

This characteristic is not unique to IEEE 754 floating point numbers, though that is where it is most famously exploited in Quake III Arena's [fast inverse square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) which uses a [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) `float`. However it will work in an abstract format like Knuth's `MIX` didactic format, or with others, including the below examples.

To the best of my understanding, the relationship was first recorded in the academic press with John Mitchell's 1961 [Computer Multiplication and Division Using Binary Logarithms](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5219391) demonstrating the method with an abstract binary logarithm system. William Kahan implemented a similar scheme around 1961 or 1962 on an IBM 7090. We know as well, in part due to Noah Hellman's masters thesis, [Mitchell-Based Approximate Operations on Floating-Point Numbers](http://liu.diva-portal.org/smash/record.jsf?pid=diva2%3A1590166&dswid=-3215), that it was also implemented in UNIX as the system square root from 1974 until the creation of a libm for BSD 4.3 in the mid 1980s. Around that same time, Kahan and his graduate student K-C Ng produced but did not publish a 'magic' square root using this method designed to operate on not `floats` but `doubles` which would be halved and operated on as 32 bit parts (see a [related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70734556/what-purpose-is-the-lookup-table-serving-in-this-code)).

It will not, however, work for all floating point formats. DEC's [VAX floating point format](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nssdc/formats/VAXFloatingPoint.htm) interleaves the sign, exponent and fraction portion (which it splits into two) so it won't do.

### What I am not asking

I don't care (for this question) about how engineers came to learn about this relationship, or where it has been exploited (cf the FISR). I want to know why it exists. Historical questions I've asked which sort of relate to the topic would be found on the retrocomputing stack exchange: [early examples of indexing float bits in C](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/26352/what-is-the-earliest-use-in-c-of-indexing-the-bits-of-a-float-or-double-to-sampl), [type punning and C standards/compilers](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/26314/when-did-type-punning-through-violating-the-strict-aliasing-rule-become-disallow)

I'm also not asking how to do it, though a good answer might include an illustrative example with some code. However, you should first take a look at this amazing FISR question on [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9027/fast-inverse-square-root) to see some really interesting ones.

### An excellent answer

A bad answer might be "any working engineer with a slide rule would understand this relationship," though I could imagine that a great answer might resort to a slide rule. Another bad answer might be "because Knuth says so," while a very good answer might include that sentiment amidst an explanation which depends on section 4.2.4 of Volume 2 of TAOCP (I don't have page numbers, I have O'Reilly's pagination abomination, it is pp. 240-247 in the print first edition).

An excellent answer should provide a clear understanding of the nature of the relationship and why it arises. A proof that the relationship must be so would be intruiging, though I can forsee some challenges.

### Why I am asking

I am writing a history of the Fast Inverse Square Root, information about which is collected at [0x5f37642f.com](https://0x5f37642f.com/). Part of investigating this as a historian means asking questions like this from the community. I do not have the expertise to distill, by myself, much of this because I am not a mathematician or a computer scientist.

The FISR has basically three interesting parts: the logarimic approximation, the "magic" constant", and newton's method. Between the three when folks write about the FISR they write about the magic constant, then newton's method, then spend **very** little time talking about the approximation. I get the feeling from the broader 'literature' that the approximation is widely known but not as clearly well understood. What I learn from answers will help me understand it.

An excellent answer will be noted in the acknowledgements of papers or talks which come out of this work.

I'm also asking because c'mon, no one has asked this yet and we've been here HOW long?

### Related questions and answers on stackoverflow

- [Answer using the logarithm trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32163873/1188479)
- [Another njuffa answer with the logarithm trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40519989/1188479)
- [Answer which explicitly references Schraudolph's 1999 paper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53872265/how-do-you-process-exp-with-sse2/53872588#53872588)
- [Somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48231407/1188479)
- [narrow answer with the trick, referencing the FISR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12342949/1188479)

Comment: Well, let's say a floating point number comprises an exponent and a mantissa, with the exponent being a base-2 logarithm and the mantissa bits concatenated to it. If you imagine a decimal point after the exponent, i.e., divide by 2 to the number of mantissa bits, you have something that equals (floor(log2(x))).(stuff) where stuff goes from 0 to 1 -- I think that's your piecewise linear interpretation. That's not dependent on the IEEE definition as such, just that a number is exponent + mantissa.

Comment: Also, as much as IEEE floats are programming related, this is still 100% a question for (also) asking over on https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'll potentially ask over there but there are people who post here whose input I am interested in.

Comment: Be that as it may, @njuffa, I’ve heard from a few people that a slide rule serves as good metaphor. Never having using one I don’t know one way or another.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm going to limit my answer to the question, "Why does the
integer representation of a floating point number offer a
piecewise linear approximation to the logarithm?".
The fast inverse square root is a fascinating topic, but I don't
know enough about it to talk about it.

But it's actually pretty easy to answer the question in the title.  First I'll start with the "TL;DR" summary:

> This approximation works because when a number is an exact power of the base, its logarithm is (trivially) exactly its exponent when expressed in exponential notation.  Floating-point notations like IEEE-754 *are* base-2 exponential notations, and the exponent occupies almost the highest-precision bits of the format, excepting only the sign bit, which is 0 for positive numbers and so can be ignored.  And all of lower-precision bits (that is, beneath the exponent) form a perfectly linear progression, notionally from 000 to 999, due in part to the fact that IEEE-754 formats use normalized significands with a "hidden" leading 1 bit.

The longer explanation starts with a review: What do we mean by a *logarithm*?
Well, it's the inverse of the exponential or power function.
Exponentials say things like, ten to the second power
(10<sup>2</sup>) is 100.  So the (base 10) logarithm function
asks things like, What power do we have to raise 10 to to get the
number 100?  The answer, of course, is 2.

You can also ask things like, "What power do we have to raise 10 to to get the
number 50?"  That's obviously harder, because 50 isn't an even
power of 10.  There's some very cool math behind this which I am
not going to try to explain, but raising things to fractional
powers is defined in such a way that 10<sup>1.69897</sup> is 50.
So the log (base 10) of 50 is 1.69897.

And then you don't have to limit yourself to powers of 10, either.
Mathematicians like to use powers of the special number *e*
(2.71828), and of course computer programmers love (just love) to
use powers of 2.  What power do we have to raise 2 to in order to
get the number 32?  Every computer geek knows it's 5.  So the log
(base 2) of 32 is 5.

And then there's scientific notation.  Let's take the number 12345.
One way of representing that in scientific notation is 1.2345
× 10<sup>4</sup>.  And it turns out that gives us a hint as
to what the base-10 logarithm of 12345 is.  It's going to be
greater than or equal to 4, and less than 5.  (In fact it's about 4.09149.)
This works as long as we pick scientific representations that are
*normalized* in a certain way, with the *significand* part
(popularly called the "mantissa") chosen to be
between 1 and 10.  (That is, we wouldn't get a good estimate of
the logarithm in this way if we'd looked at the otherwise-equivalent
notations 0.12345 × 10<sup>5</sup> or 12.345 × 10<sup>3</sup>.)

So now let's turn to computer floating-point representations.
These typically use — and IEEE-754 definitely uses — base-2
(binary) exponential representations, that is, with normalized
significand values multiplied by some power of 2.  For example,
the number 1.125 is represented as 1.125 × 2<sup>0</sup>,
the number 25.25 is represented as 1.578125 × 2<sup>4</sup>,
and the number 0.1875 is represented as 1.5 × 2<sup>-3</sup>.

And, just as for base 10, those exponents give us a rough,
integer-only approximation of the base-2 logarithm — again,
as long as we use normalized significands, in this case between 1 and 2.
So log<sub>2</sub>(25.25) is going to be somewhere between 4 and 5.

It's also time for me to foreshadow
a super-special secret fact implied by the fact that
we're restricting ourselves to normalized significand values.
I said they were going to be "between 1 and 2", but more
precisely, they're going to range from 1.00000 to 1.99999.
But notice that no matter what the significand value is,
for base 2 *the first digit is always going to be 1*.
In a minute we'll see what we can do with that.

The IEEE-754 binary floating-point representations all consist of
a sign bit, followed by some number of exponent bits, followed
by some number of significand bits.  For example, for our number
25.25, we're going to have a 0 bit representing a positive sign,
followed by some representation of the exponent 4, followed by
some representation of the significand 1.578125.

But now we're getting a glimmer of how the raw-bits
interpretation of a floating-point number might have something to
do with a logarithm.  For positive numbers we don't have to worry
about the sign bit (since it's 0), and the next thing we see is
going to be the exponent, and we've already seen that the
exponent is a rough (integer-only) approximation of the
logarithm.  So all that's left to ask is, how are we going to
interpolate between the power-of-two values that have exact
base-2 logarithms
(log<sub>2</sub>(8) = 3, log<sub>2</sub>(16) = 4,
log<sub>2</sub>(32) = 5, etc.)
and the fractional ones in between?

If I gave you evenly-spaced numbers like 100, 200, 300 and asked
you to fill in the numbers in between, you'd have little trouble:
you'd replace the 00 part by 01, 02, 03, ..., up to 99.
And if you knew anything about binary numbers,
and I asked you do do the same for evenly-spaced binary numbers like

```
00100000
01000000
01100000
10000000
```

you could do more or less the same thing, replacing the `00000`
part by consecutive binary numbers `00001`, `00010`, `00011`, etc.

Remarkably enough, we're about to see that something *exactly
like this* goes on when we encode significand values in IEEE-754
floating-point numbers.

Let's start looking at an actual IEEE-754
floating-point format.  We'll use single-precision float32, to
keep the numbers halfway reasonable.  This format uses 1 bit for
the sign (S), 8 bits for the exponent (e), and 23 bits for the
significand (s):

```
S e e e e e e e e s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s
```

Let's start figuring out what the representations of the numbers
16.000 = 2<sup>4</sup> and 32.000 = 2<sup>5</sup> would look like.

16 is 1.0 × 2<sup>4</sup>.  So the significand is 1.0, and the
exponent is 4.  How will these be stored?  I'm going to
concentrate on the significand first.  Remember the observation
that the first digit (the one to the left of the decimal point)
is always 1?  IEEE-754 takes the position that this always-1 leading bit *does not need to be stored at all*.  The
actual bits stored for a significand of 1.0 will be 00000.
The exponent will be some representation of 4.  So I'm going to
represent the number 16.000 like this:

```
0 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Those "4"s are approximate; I still haven't gotten around to
explaining how the exponent is encoded.

The number 32.000 is similar — actually, it's identical, except
for the exponent:

```
0 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

But the key point I'm building up to is that the numbers in
between — those greater than 16.0, but less than 32.0, will all
be variations on

```
0 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

except with the 0's replaced by all the consecutive 23-bit binary
numbers — all 2^23 or 8388608 of them — from 000…001 up to 111…111.

So now we've got just about all the pieces in place to see how
"the
integer representation of a floating point number offers a
piecewise linear approximation to the logarithm".  We've shown
that the binary representations of the numbers between 16 and 32
form a nice, linear ramp from a number that starts with something
like 4, to a number that starts with something like 5.

I've been ducking the question of how the exponents are encoded.
That's done using a *bias* scheme.  For binary32, the bit pattern
stored is the actual exponent value, plus 127.  So our exponent
value of 4 will be stored as a bit pattern of 4+127=131, and 5
will be stored as 132.  So the *actual* encodings of 16.0 and
32.0 will be

```
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

where I have filled in the binary values of the encoded exponents 131 and 132, namely
`10000011` and `10000100`.  And now we can see the actual, raw values

`01000001100000000000000000000000` and
`01000010000000000000000000000000`, or `0x41800000` and
`0x42000000`, or 1098907648 and 1107296256.

Those numbers don't have anything obvious to do with the base-2
logarithms of 16 and 32 (namely, 4 and 5), but they're actually
very close.  They're offset by the effect of the bias, and
they're completely wrong in magnitude.  But that's not surprising:
by taking 32-bit quantities and treating them as integers, we're
getting big numbers (which are indeed integers), but the actual
values for these logarithms should be 4.0 and 5.0, and we'd like
the possibility of a fractional part.  So if we're going to treat
these big integers as some rendition of the logarithms of some
other, smaller numbers, it's going to involve something very much
like a *fixed-point* representation.

Deriving the details of that fixed-point representation is
straightforward: the scaling factor is clearly 2<sup>23</sup> =
8388608, and there's also an offset, corresponding to the bias
built in to the binary32 format.  That offset will be 1065353216
(127 × 2<sup>23</sup>)
if applied before scaling, or 127 afterwards.

Let's see if this works.  We have come up with integer values of
1098907648 and 1107296256 corresponding to 16.0 and 32.0.  So:

```
(1098907648 - 1065353216) / 8388608 = 4
(1107296256 - 1065353216) / 8388608 = 5
```

or the other way:

```
1098907648 / 8388608 - 127 = 4
1107296256 / 8388608 - 127 = 5
```

So it's working!

It's said that a picture is worth 1,000 words, and it's long past time to do some of this explaining that way.  Here's a graph which — not coincidentally — looks an awful lot like the one you posted from Mitchell 1961:

[image: graph of log2(x), and piecewise linear approximation]

The red curve is the actual base-2 log function.  The black dots are the places where log<sub>2</sub>(X) is an integer.  Those are the points where the raw bits of a binary32 float value, interpreted as an integer and suitably scaled, are exactly equal to log<sub>2</sub>.  And then in blue we have straight line segments directly connecting those points.

To recap: If we take the raw bits of binary32 float values corresponding to exact powers of 2, we get:

| X | binary32 (hex) | binary32 (dec) | log<sub>2</sub> |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.25 | `3e800000` | 1048576000 | -2 |
| 0.5 | `3f000000` | 1056964608 | -1 |
| 1 | `3f800000` | 1065353216 | 0 |
| 2 | `40000000` | 1073741824 | 1 |
| 4 | `40800000` | 1082130432 | 2 |
| 8 | `41000000` | 1090519040 | 3 |
| 16 | `41800000` | 1098907648 | 4 |
| 32 | `42000000` | 1107296256 | 5 |

An exact power of two has a significand of 1.0 (that is, these numbers are all 1.0 × 2<sup>N</sup>), meaning that they are encoded in IEEE-754 as all 0's (due to the "hidden 1 bit" property).
And since they're positive, their sign bit is 0 also, and the only part that isn't 0 is the exponent.  And since for exact powers the exponent *is* the logarithm, for these numbers, the integer interpretation of the raw bit pattern is always exactly the logarithm, after shifting and scaling.  (I presume that some aspect of that "shifting and scaling" is where the magic number 0x5f37642f comes in.)

And then, for all the numbers that aren't exact powers of 2, and for which the logarithm isn't an integer, the way the significand values are laid out means that the raw values (as shown by the blue lines in the plot above) form a perfect linear interpolation between the exact powers.  Therefore, in (almost) all cases, the raw bit patterns do indeed end up being a "piecewise linear approximation to the logarithm".  (I said "almost" because this result does *not* hold for the subnormals, and for the special values Inf and NaN.)

The other interpretation of the question "Why" is, "Why did the designers of IEEE-754 set things up this way?"  I don't believe it was deliberate, that is, I don't believe that it was a requirement that the raw bit pattern, interpreted as an integer, corresponded to a piecewise linear approximation of the base-2 logarithm.  However, given these three related facts:

- the definition of an exponential notation basically *is* a piecewise approximation of a logarithm
- IEEE-754 did have a goal of keeping positive floating-point values monotonically increasing per their raw bit values
- IEEE-754 hides the high-order "1" bit of the significand; all significands are of the form 1.xxx but only the xxx part is stored as such

the "piecewise liner approximation" result falls out rather neatly.

Comment: Thank you for adding the picture. I didn't want to clutter the question by adding one but looking at yours I think I will add one (probably from an old source for fun). Reading through your answer now.

Comment: Added two images from references which were in the question and one from J.M. Muller's chapter, which I have just now added.

Comment: This is a great answer and the work you have put into it is evident. I have started a bounty but I hope you see from the text that you are very much the answer to beat. I hope this page can become the reference I wish I had when I ran into the FISR in 2009.

Comment: @AdamHyland Thanks, and no worries about the bounty.  I'm not perfectly satisfied with this answer, either, and I wouldn't mind seeing a better (hopefully more concise!) one.

Answer (score 11):

The quoted text in the question is factually incorrect. A more accurate version would read: The bit pattern of a *positive normal* *IEEE-754 floating point number*, interpreted as a *fixed-point* number and *adjusted for exponent bias*, gives a piecewise linear approximation to the *binary* logarithm function.

In order for the technique to work, the floating-point format must be binary, and the most significant bit of the significand must be implicit and not actually stored. Furthermore it must store the significand in a contiguous block of least significant bits, and the exponent in the *immediately abutting* contiguous block of more significant bits. Some floating-point formats preceding IEEE-754 fulfill these requirements, but many do not.

The technique works because IEEE-754 floating-point formats use a *semi*-logarithmic representation, with the exponent providing a logarithmic scale but the significand providing linear scale subdivisions between those. This is different from a slide rule , which is fully logarithmic, i.e. both major divisions and sub-divisions follow a logarithmic scale.

If we have a **positive normal** IEEE-754 `binary32` number `y`, its stored exponent `E` is the true exponent `e` plus the exponent bias of 127. Of the significand `s`, which is in [1,2), only the fractional part `f` in [0, 1) is stored, that is `s = 1 + f`, as the most significant bit of the significand is implicit. The value of the number `y` is 2<sup>e</sup> * (1 + f). Its binary logarithm is log<sub>2</sub> (2<sup>e</sup> * (1 + f)) = log<sub>2</sub> (2<sup>e</sup>) + log<sub>2</sub> (1 + f). Given the domain of `f`, a very simple and rough approximation is log<sub>2</sub> (1 + f) = f (note that this matches the mathematical result at the end points), so log<sub>2</sub> (2<sup>e</sup> * (1 + f)) ≈ e + f.

In other words: **with the exponent bias subtracted out**, the number `y` represents an **s8.23 fixed-point representation** of a rough approximation of the binary logarithm of `y`. To convert this into a floating-point number divide by 2<sup>23</sup> or alternatively multiply by 2<sup>-23</sup>. To make this process more efficient on most modern processors, one can subtract out the exponent bias at the very end of the process instead of at the very start. This results in the following exemplary ISO-C99 implementation with a maximum absolute error of 8.6e-2:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

uint32_t float_as_uint32 (float x) 
{ 
    uint32_t r; 
    memcpy (&r, &x, sizeof r); 
    return r; 
} 

float fastest_log2 (float y)
{
    const int FP32_EXPO_BIAS = 127;
    const float two_to_m23 = 1.192092896e-7f; // 0x1.0p-23
    float x = (float)(int) float_as_uint32 (y);
    return x * two_to_m23 - (float) FP32_EXPO_BIAS;
}
```

On hardware that supports fused multiply-add operations and with appropriate compiler settings, the last line of `fastest_log2()` should map to some flavor of FMA.

Comment: Good answer, yet "In order for the technique to work, the floating-point format must be binary" and " most significant bit of the significand must be implicit and not actually stored" is not true, in general.  Yes having those 2 limitations does help sample code.

Comment: One limitation not yet mentioned: endian of the `float` and `uint32_t` needs to be the same.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica In order to **simply re-interpret** (e.g. the `float_to_uint32()` in my code) the bit pattern of a floating-point number as a fixed-point number that approximates the binary logarithm (**the claim from the question**), the floating point format must be binary and with implicit leading bit and the components ordered as stated. If those conditions are not met, one would first need to use bit manipulations to re-arrange bits, and in case of IBM hexadecimal floating-point format do base-conversion of the exponent. That is beyond what is claimed.

Answer (score 6):

This answer discusses positive, finite normal numbers in binary floating-point formats. (The premise does not hold for zeros, negative numbers, infinities, subnormal numbers, and NaNs.)

A floating-point number *y* is represented as ±*b*<sup>*e*</sup>*s* for a fixed base *b*, an integer exponent *e*, and a significand *s*, 0 ≤ *s* < *b*. For normal forms, 1 ≤ *s* < *b*. For binary formats, *b* is 2. For positive numbers, the sign is of course +. For any particular floating-point format, there are bounds on *e* and bounds on both the magnitude and the precision of *s* (the number of base-*b* digits in *s*). For general discussion of this answer, the particular characteristics do not greatly concern us, although they may be introduced at points.

Given *y* = 2<sup>*e*</sup>*s*, log<sub>2</sub> *y* = log<sub>2</sub> (2<sup>*e*</sup>*s*) = *e* + log<sub>2</sub> *s*.

In the IEEE 754 “single precision” format, binary32, commonly used for `float`, a normal number 2<sup>*e*</sup>*s* is encoded as a 0 bit for the sign, 8 bits that are the binary for *e*+127, and 23 bits that are the binary for (*s*−1)2<sup>23</sup>. Reinterpreting these 32 bits as a binary numeral (most significant to least significant in the order listed above) yields the value (*e*+127)2<sup>23</sup>+(*s*−1)2<sup>23</sup> = (*e*+126+*s*)2<sup>23</sup>.

> My question is, what is it about floating point numbers which gives rise to this characteristic?

As we can see above, reinterpreting the encoding of a floating-point number, particularly the IEEE-754 binary32, does **not** give an approximation of the logarithm, as it is completely out of scale and biased by an offset.

However, if we consider the adjustment f(*x*) = x/2<sup>23</sup>−127, then f(*y* reinterpreted as binary) = f((*e*+126+*s*)2<sup>23</sup>) = (*e*+126+*s*)2<sup>23</sup>/2<sup>23</sup>−127 = *e*+*s*−1. Now we see we have the exponent *e* of *y*; this value *e*+*s*−1 is at least near log<sub>2</sub> *y* = *e* + log<sub>2</sub> *s*. Thus, it is an approximation of log<sub>2</sub> *y*. (Also note that *s*−1 is 0 and 1 at *s* = 1 and 2, respectively, the same as log<sub>2</sub> *s*. So it serves as an approximation of log<sub>2</sub> *s* over the interval the significand covers.)

If we take each value of *e* as one piece for the piecewise linear approximation, the approximation *e*+*s*−1 is linear because it fits the linear model *e*+*s*−1 = *ay* + *b* where *a* = 2<sup>−*e*</sup> and *b* = *e*−1, as we can see since *ay* + *b* = 2<sup>−*e*</sup>*y* + *e* − 1 = 2<sup>−*e*</sup>(2<sup>*e*</sup>*s*) + *e* − 1 = *e*+*s*−1.

Regarding the adjustment function f(*x*) = x/2<sup>23</sup>−127, you will often see aspects of this in code that manipulates the encoding of floating-point numbers—it will in various ways add or subtract to account for the bias of the exponent and the leading 1 bit of the significand, and it will in various ways shift to move the exponent field where desired.